# shouldOverrideUrlLoading on local images with loadDataWithBaseURL not working

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm loading local html using `loadDataWithBaseURL` method.

I'm calling the meod `setHTML` with the source, and it's going well. the link is VALID, as i've seen in previous questions on stackoverflow, so everything is set.

When the user clicks on a link, it works and its opening the `ArticleActivity`, but when he clicks on an image (from the html), the method isn't called, even tho the image has a link.

What would be the problem here?

```
 public void setHTML(String source) {
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(source);
    String html = WebHelper.docToBetterHTML(doc, this);
    mHTMLWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(mLink, html, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
    mHTMLWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}


mHTMLWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Animation fade = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mLoadingLayout.getContext(), android.R.anim.fade_out);
                    mLoadingLayout.startAnimation(fade);
                    mLoadingLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            },500);
        }


        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
            //super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view,url);
            if(url != null
                    && (url.endsWith(".png") || url
                    .endsWith(".jpg") || url
                    .endsWith(".jpeg"))){
                // Launch imageviewer
                ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                list.add(url);


                try{
                    new ImageViewer.Builder(view.getContext(), list)
                            .setStartPosition(0)
                            .show();
                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }  else if (url != null
                    && url.contains("dkhlak.com")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),ArticleActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("link",url);
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);

            } else {
                Intent ViewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                try{
                    view.getContext().startActivity(ViewIntent);
                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            return true;
        }
        });
```

Example:

```
<p>\u0625\u0646 \u0639\u0627\u0644\u0645\u0646\u0627 \u0645\u0643\u0627\u0646\u064c \u063a\u0631\u064a\u0628\u064c \u062c\u062f\u0627\u064b\u060c \u0641\u0641\u064a \u0628\u0639\u0636 \u0627\u0644\u0623\u062d\u064a\u0627\u0646 \u064a\u0648\u062c\u062f \u0623\u0634\u064a\u0627\u0621\u064c \u0643\u062b\u064a\u0631\u0629 \u0646\u0638\u0646\u0647\u0627 \u0639\u0627\u062f\u064a\u0629\u060c \u0644\u0643\u0646\u0647\u0627 \u0642\u062f \u062a\u0643\u0648\u0646 \u0641\u064a \u0646\u0638\u0631 \u063a\u064a\u0631\u0646\u0627 \u0645\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0646\u0627\u0633 \u063a\u064a\u0631 \u0639\u0627\u062f\u064a\u0629\u060c \u0628\u0644 \u0623\u0646\u0647\u0645 \u0642\u062f \u064a\u0631\u0648\u0646\u0647\u0627 \u0642\u0628\u064a\u062d\u0629. \u0644\u0643\u0646 \u0641\u064a \u0627\u0644\u0646\u0647\u0627\u064a\u0629 \u064a\u0648\u062c\u062f \u0623\u0634\u064a\u0627\u0621 \u0646\u062c\u0645\u0639 \u0643\u0644\u0646\u0627 \u0639\u0644\u0649 \u0642\u0628\u062d\u0647\u0627 \u0648\u0628\u063a\u0636\u0647\u0627\u060c \u0648\u0630\u0644\u0643 \u0644\u0623\u0646\u0647\u0627 \u063a\u064a\u0631 \u0625\u0646\u0633\u0627\u0646\u064a\u0629 \u0648\u0638\u0627\u0644\u0645\u0629 \u0644\u062f\u0631\u062c\u0629 \u063a\u064a\u0631 \u0642\u0627\u0628\u0644\u0629 \u0644\u0644\u062a\u0635\u0648\u0631.<\/p>\n<p>\u0648\u0645\u0647\u0645\u0627 \u0643\u0627\u0646 \u0642\u0628\u062d \u062a\u0644\u0643 \u0627\u0644\u0623\u0634\u064a\u0627\u0621 \u0643\u0628\u064a\u0631\u0627\u064b\u061b \u064a\u0628\u0642\u0649 \u0644\u062f\u064a\u0646\u0627 \u0641\u0636\u0648\u0644 \u0643\u0628\u064a\u0631 \u0644\u0645\u0639\u0631\u0641\u0629 \u0645\u0627\u0647\u064a\u062a\u0647\u0627\u060c \u0641\u0641\u064a \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0642\u0627\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u062a\u0627\u0644\u064a \u0633\u0646\u0639\u0631\u0636 \u0644\u0643\u0645 \u0633\u062a \u0639\u0634\u0631\u0629 \u062d\u0642\u064a\u0642\u0629 \u0635\u0627\u0631\u062e\u0629 \u062c\u0627\u0648\u0632\u062a \u0641\u064a \u0642\u0628\u062d\u0647\u0627 \u0623\u0628\u0639\u062f \u0627\u0644\u062d\u062f\u0648\u062f:<\/p>\n<p><strong>1. \u0641\u064a \u0645\u0637\u0644\u0639 \u0627\u0644\u0642\u0631\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0639\u0634\u0631\u064a\u0646\u060c \u0639\u064f\u0631\u0636 \u0627\u0644\u0631\u062c\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0643\u0648\u0646\u063a\u0648\u0644\u064a Ota Benga \u0641\u064a \u0623\u062d\u062f \u0623\u0642\u0641\u0627\u0635 \u0627\u0644\u0642\u0631\u062f\u0629 \u0641\u064a \u062d\u062f\u064a\u0642\u0629 Bronx \u0643\u0646\u0645\u0648\u0630\u062c \u062d\u064a \u0644\u0645\u0631\u0627\u062d\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u062a\u0637\u0648\u0631 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0634\u0631\u064a\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0628\u0643\u0631\u0629. \u0645\u0635\u064a\u0631 Benga \u0625\u0646\u062a\u0647\u0649 \u0628\u0625\u0642\u062f\u0627\u0645\u0647 \u0639\u0644\u0649 \u0627\u0644\u0625\u0646\u062a\u062d\u0627\u0631 \u0646\u062a\u064a\u062c\u0629 \u0644\u0633\u0648\u0621 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0639\u0627\u0645\u0644\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u062a\u064a \u062a\u0639\u0631\u0636 \u0625\u0644\u064a\u0647\u0627\u060c \u0648\u0627\u0644\u0625\u0643\u062a\u0626\u0627\u0628 \u0627\u0644\u0630\u064a \u0623\u0635\u0627\u0628\u0647 \u0644\u0627\u062d\u0642\u0627\u064b.<\/strong><em>\u00a0\u2014<a href=\"https:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Ota_Benga\" rel=\"nofollow\">\u0627\u0644\u0645\u0635\u062f\u0631<\/a><\/em><\/p>\n<div id=\"attachment_15079\" style=\"width: 1034px\" class=\"wp-caption aligncenter\"><img class=\"size-full wp-image-15079\" src=\"https:\/\/dkhlak.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/06\/15071-1.jpg\" alt=\"\u0627\u0644\u0631\u062c\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0643\u0648\u0646\u063a\u0648\u0644\u064a Ota Benga\" width=\"1024\" height=\"580\" srcset=\"https:\/\/dkhlak.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/06\/15071-1.jpg 1024w, https:\/\/dkhlak.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/06\/15071-1-400x227.jpg 400w, https:\/\/dkhlak.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/06\/15071-1-768x435.jpg 768w, https:\/\/dkhlak.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/06\/15071-1-810x459.jpg 810w\" sizes=\"(max-width: 1024px) 100vw, 1024px\" \/>
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the html you're using?

Comment: Im taking it from the Wordpress JSON api, so its the HTML from a wordpress article.

Comment: Ok, but can you provide an example of one of those images you're having trouble with? Doesn't need to be the whole html. I'm guessing the problem lies in the "target" parameter.

Comment: I've added an example, its not a full example of the HTML, just cropped it from the start til the point where an image is included.

Comment: The img tag in the example you shared doesn't have a link, it's not enclosed in "<a href='www.foo.bar'></a>".

Comment: That seems to be the problem.

Comment: Because i've cropped the html, you can check it here fully: dkhlak.com/10-rejected-designs-for-american-flag/?json=1 , check the json object "content"